# Openldap JNDI extended operations

Tags: jndi, openldap

I have openldap with extended operations like:

```
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 7776002
pwdExpireWarning: 432000
pwdInHistory: 3
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinLength: 6
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 900
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

I would like know by JNDI (LdapContext) how to obtain the expire warning, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some extended controls. See the `PasswordPolicyRequest/ResponseControl` code and factory I posted in the [Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/message/4695560#4695560).